# what is wrong with a relational DB and why would you switch to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I was looking trough their website and I can't understand the problem that they are solving. What is the problem with the relational DB? How can be data stored in JSON documents any faster than the data stored in an SQL database?

Answer (score 2):

In a fully normalized relational DB, every insertion will often require several look-ups in other tables (and its own table) to maintain data integrity (FKs). This is generally a good thing, but takes time. It's also often the case that you need to update several rows in different tables at once, leading to even more look-ups and transactional overhead.

Querying the database will also often need to look at many different tables and merge them.

A mongoDB document on the other hand is a much simpler construct. Every collection is like a big un-normalized table but where all fields are optional (but still indexable), so there is very little space overhead (compared to a relational DB with the same setup).

It offers flexibility and speed at the cost of complex querying and removing data integrity logic from the server to the client (database client, not end user client ;)).

Both has its uses, but the question that has normally been "do we need something different from a Relational DB?" should nowadays be "do we need something more complex than a document DB?" imo, and the vast majority of projects will not.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're happy with relational database for you task, you needn't switch to mongoDb. I think mongodb is supposed to make scaling out simpler than for rdbms. For some tasks I think I think you can get benefits from flexible schema in mongodb as well. I think it mostly make sense to discuss using some database for a concrete task.